# how do i return a object with a properties values changed

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
  if (typeof (column) == "object"){
  
       const arrOfNum = data.coins.map((coin)=> {

       return Number(coin[price])
        })
```

expected output :
{
"uuid": "Qwsogvtv82FCd",
"symbol": "BTC",
"name": "Bitcoin",
"color": "#f7931A",
"iconUrl": "https://cdn.coinranking.com/bOabBYkcX/bitcoin_btc.svg",
"marketCap": "785319372537",
"price": "41293.05936358471",
"listedAt": 1330214400,
"tier": 1,
"change": "0.17",
"rank": 1,
"sparkline": [
"41221.7332808813672928470000",
"41246.7311302204428981710000",
"41440.6207846152960872210000",
"41472.9647655491877352100000",
"41382.0616505004118164040000",
"41458.9435740188725319780000",
"41554.8756538362515840770000",
"41643.5106357550083772420000",
"41614.5446056686015453980000",
"41645.8468940151604576290000",
"41615.8933395604524087530000",
"41445.3113844073524616890000",
"41529.0627077609878445810000",
"41677.3473433344974606810000",
"41876.2047747023076004360000",
"41825.3035545206968729250000",
"42238.9699991003198750480000",
"42445.7423310527608033750000",
"42693.3414187991114196250000",
"42591.9826184876248138850000",
"42528.8906252930777354680000",
"42207.9275249499580366980000",
"41954.8342609382093874200000",
"41647.9469247455994165110000",
"41567.7298132234881619570000",
"41436.3047062927935743720000",
"41293.0593635847100000000000"
],
"lowVolume": false,
"coinrankingUrl": "https://coinranking.com/coin/Qwsogvtv82FCd+bitcoin-btc",
"24hVolume": "27526958013",
"btcPrice": "1"
}
I Want To go through an array of objects and Replace The Old Object with a new object that contains the number value of price instead of the string value.

Comment: Please post more data. Like the input object and expected output

Comment: i edited the post